# Adding elements from an array to a sql query in PHP

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to put an array with values returned from a function to a sql query in PHP. Looking for information on how to do this, I tried to change the format of the array with the parameters fetch_assoc and fetch array, but it didn't help. I also tried to do a foreach loop for this array and execute sql with each iteration, but it also didn't do anything. How can I do this ?
This is my function which returns me an array of values:

```
public static function getLilanteProductCategoryForEmpik() {
            $returnedArray = [];
    
            $pdo = PDOConnector::getConnection();
            
            echo $query = "SELECT product_type FROM `shopifyProductsLilante` 
                            INNER JOIN offers_import_error_report_3839_14794292 
                            WHERE shopifyProductsLilante.sku=offers_import_error_report_3839_14794292.sku";
    
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
            $stmt->execute( );
                    
            while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                $returnedArray[] = $row;
            }
            var_dump($returnedArray);

            return $returnedArray;
        }
```

and this is the function where I want to put the values from the array in the sql query:

```
public static function getEmpikCategoryToCSVFile() {
            $returnedArray = [];
            $lilanteProductCategory = MysqlProvider::getLilanteProductCategoryForEmpik();
    
            $pdo = PDOConnector::getConnection();
            foreach($lilanteProductCategory as $lilanteCategory)
            {
                echo $query = "SELECT empik_category FROM `empik_categories` INNER JOIN shopifyProductsLilante 
                            WHERE  $lilanteCategory=empik_categories.lilante_category";
            }          
                
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
            $stmt->execute( );
                    
            while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                $returnedArray[] = $row;
            }
            print_r($returnedArray);

            return $returnedArray;
        }
```

Comment: This is not how SQL works. You need to define each field as an seperate WHERE / OR.

Comment: Pretty sure you could just write one query for this e.g. `SELECT empik_category FROM \`empik_categories\` INNER JOIN shopifyProductsLilante 
                            WHERE  empik_categories.lilante_category IN (SELECT product_type FROM \`shopifyProductsLilante\` INNER JOIN offers_import_error_report_3839_14794292 ON shopifyProductsLilante.sku=offers_import_error_report_3839_14794292.sku)`

Comment: Or actually, maybe even just `SELECT empik_category FROM \`empik_categories\` INNER JOIN shopifyProductsLilante ON empik_categories.lilante_category = shopifyProductsLilante.product_type INNER JOIN offers_import_error_report_3839_14794292 ON shopifyProductsLilante.sku=offers_import_error_report_3839_14794292.sku)` . Maybe depends precisely what the result set should be at the end. Give it a try.

Comment: Thank you, the result is not what I need yet, but at least I know which direction to go in to modify the query